# Is `T array[N]{}` a value initialization or aggregate initialization?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, language-lawyer

Consider some type `T` (for simplicity, you may assume `int`) and some integral constant `N`, which we use to define an array like this:

```
T array[N]{}; // Note the empty braces here!
```

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization), value initialization is defined as follows:

> This is the initialization performed when an object is constructed with an empty initializer.

But further down it is written:

> In all cases, if the empty pair of braces {} is used and T is an aggregate type, aggregate-initialization is performed instead of value-initialization.

But then a little bit more down, the following statement appears:

> 3. if T is an array type, each element of the array is value-initialized;

From my understanding, the first and third quoted statements contradict to the second one.

So my two questions are:

- Is the code snippet above a value initialization or an aggregate initialization?
- Do the three quoted statements really contradict or am I missing something?

Note: I've seen similar questions here but they all differ a bit in the specifics.

Comment: The last one applies, since you are dealing with arrays. And no, they don't contradict eachother. The first quote is just a quick summary at the top of the page, it's not gone into detail yet. The second quote is specific to aggregate types, and the third is for arrays; so the last two are dealing with different types.

Comment: But arrays _are_ aggregate types, aren't they? At least [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) it says: _"An aggregate is one of the following types: array type [...]"_

Comment: one quote talks about initialization of `T` the other of the elements of `T` (when its an array). I see no contradiction

Comment: fwiw, as you tagged as language lawyer, you might look it up in the standard. cppreference is usually rather accurate, but still not as accurate as the standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `T array[N]{}` a value initialization or aggregate initialization?

It is [list initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.list) and part of this initialization process involves [aggregate initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.aggr) as per [dcl.init.list](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.list). Additionally, it is also *direct list initialization* as quoted below.

> **1**) **List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list.** Such an initializer is called an initializer list, and the comma-separated initializer-clauses of the initializer-list or designated-initializer-clauses of the designated-initializer-list are called the elements of the initializer list. **An initializer list may be empty.** List-initialization can occur in direct-initialization or copy-initialization contexts; list-initialization in a direct-initialization context is called *direct-list-initialization* and list-initialization in a copy-initialization context is called copy-list-initialization.
>
> [Note 1 : **List-initialization can be used**
>
> **(1.1)** **as the initializer in a variable definition** ([dcl.init])
>
> ...
>
> — end note]

The above means that `T array[N]{}` is list-initialization.

---

Now let's move on to how the elements of the array is initialized which is given in [dcl.init.list#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.list#3):

> **3)** List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> **3.4)** Otherwise, **if `T` is an aggregate, aggregate initialization is performed.**

And since in our example `T array[N]` is an [aggregate](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.aggr), the above implies that in our example the whole process of initialization of the array `T array[N]` involves *aggregate initialization*.

---

Finally, from [aggregate initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.aggr) given below, we will note that each element is **copy-initialized** from an empty initializer list:

> **3)** When an aggregate is initialized by an initializer list as specified in [dcl.init.list], the elements of the initializer list are taken as initializers for the elements of the aggregate. **The explicitly initialized elements of the aggregate are determined as follows**:
>
> **3.3)** Otherwise, **the initializer list must be {}, and there are no explicitly initialized elements.**

---

The above means that there are no **explicitly initialized elements** in our example so we move onto [dcl.init.aggr#5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.aggr#5):

> **5)** For a non-union aggregate, **each element that is not an explicitly initialized element is initialized as follows**:
>
> **5.2)** Otherwise, **if the element is not a reference, the element is copy-initialized from an empty initializer list**.

(emphasis mine)

Essentially, this means that each element of type `T` of the array will be initialized from an *empty initializer list*.

---

Note that this also explains why the following *contrived example* [fails in C++20](https://godbolt.org/z/8nndYs1ej):

```
struct T
{
    T() = delete;
};
int main() 
{
    T array[5]{}; //this fails as a consequence of above explanation
}
```